# Makes Switch - Literally!

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Happy Venndredi everyone!

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions - your task is to place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged into an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Makes Switch: NINTENDO
>  Sorry: PENITENT
>  Pre-84: NINETEEN

Resulting in full venn diagram of:

> [image: Venn Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the 3 words are:

> NINTENDO, NINETEEN, and PENITENT

So,

> Makes switch is just 'DO', Pre-84 is just 'NE', and Sorry is just 'PE'.

the overlaps are:

> 'EN' in the top, 'TE' in the right', and 'NT' in the left.

With the center containing:

> 'NI'